# Explicit example of a discontinuous function between convergence spaces with the preimage of every open set open

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, set-theory, examples-counterexamples, filters

The definition of continuity for [convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space#:%7E:text=A%20convergence%20space%20is%20topological,category%20Top%20of%20topological%20spaces.) is in terms of filters, but it’s still true that the preimage of any open set is open. Since this is no longer taken as the def of continuity, I wanted to see if there’s an explicit example of a *discontinuous* function between convergence spaces that still satisfies “preimage of every open set is open”. Of course, these spaces would have to be non-topological.

Comment: What does an open set mean if we are dealing with a convergence space?

Comment: A subset O of a convergence space is open iff whenever a filter converges to some x in O, then there’s a subset from the filter contained in O.